# how to add existing eclipse project to existing git repo

Tags: java, eclipse, git, egit

I am working on a shared git project on eclipse that consists of 3 eclipse projects within one git repo.

I've created a new project which I want to add to the repo, so that it will be the 4th project in that repo.

How do I add that using egit?

I right-clicked it and did 'share' and I thought I added it to the repo. The project reference in [] after the project name has changed to be the same as the other projects, but apart from that, I can't see that it's been added in any way. I thought its files would show up in the staging view, since they are untracked, but they are not there..

Many thanks for any advice

Comment: Are your eclipse projects subdirectories of your git repo directory?

Comment: Ah I think I figured it out thanks. I just needed to do the extra step of shared -> add to index (after adding an appropriate gitignore.